# adb push command not working android kitkat(4.4)

Tags: android

I am newbie to android,
I want to push files into application internal memory from PC,
adb push command is working fine all in android versions but not in Kitkat(4.4) saying permission denied
I stuck at this issue, please help me on this.

Comment: Ok thanks but how to solve my problem, is there any way to modify the chmodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adb requires authorization from the device itself in recent releases. See [this announcement](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements43.html) which mentions:

> Since Android 4.2.2, connections to ADB are authenticated with an RSA keypair. This prevents unauthorized use of ADB where the attacker has physical access to a device

Once you enable developer mode, starting adb should cause the phone to show a prompt asking you to authorize the new connection.